System unexpectedly wakes up from resume if battery reports its charge as empty
I rewired my laptop's battery with external cables, so it never physically drains out. However, as expected, the charge counter within the battery counts down. The PC continues working even if the battery reports its state as empty.
However, when the battery reports an empty state, system wakes up from a suspend. If I plug the charger, it stays in suspended state. When I unplug the charger, it stays in suspended state, until battery "runs out".
So, I can not reliably keep my laptop suspended without the AC charger. Whenever it reports it's empty, laptop wakes up.
How can I fix this situation?

I would expect a system to wake up and perform a clean shutdown with the last few ergs. Why not replace the battery, and use the laptop's charger?

Why would you expect such a thing? What if I didn't only suspend the PC, but I had hibernated it? Would you still expect to resume and shutdown? This is against the definition of hibernation in the first place.
